# Include numbers in the first column once and transpose them as column headers

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am working with data from the hospital, and when I add the .csv extension to my text files they output in the following way:

[image: Data Sample]

It would be much easier to manage if there were a way to only include the numbers in the first column once, and also transpose them as column headers. And go through the first ten in the second column, add and transpose them underneath, then do the next ten. The final product looking like this:

[image: Final Result]

I have tried transposing them manually, but since there are millions of files, the CSV's are quite extensive. I have looked for a way in Excel to do it, but I have found nothing.

Could someone help me with a macro for this?

Comment: Wouldn't a simple pivot table achieve the same result?

Comment: @pnuts, MiguelH - Can you do that with string data? Can you post that as an answer?  As far as I know, a pivot table's value columns will only operate as a numeric. If this is a simple Excel PivotTable, I'd definitely like to know how for future use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excel formula could be used, if the numbers are repeated exactly.

If the data is in Columns A & B, the following formula could be placed in C2:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,(ROW(C1)-1)*10+COLUMN(A$1))
```

And then copied to the right and down as far as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention whether the sequence of row numbers (1,90,100,120...) is always the same for each "row".  From your sample, I will assume that the numbers repeat the same way, ad infinitum.

First, import the CSV into Microsoft Access. Let's assume your first column is called RowID, and your second is called Description.  RowID is an integer, and Description is a memo field.

Add a third column, an Integer, and call it "Ord" (no quotes).

In Access's VBA editor add a new module with this [GroupIncrement](http://fieldeffect.info/wp/frontpage/vba_library/#GroupIncrement_Function) function:

```
Function GroupIncrement(ByVal sGroup)
    Static Num, LastGrp

    If (StrComp(LastGrp, Nz(sGroup, "")) <> 0) Then
        Num = 0
    End If
    Num = Num + 1
    GroupIncrement = Num

    LastGrp = sGroup
End Function
```

Create a new query, replacing MyTable with the name of your Access table containing the CSV data:

```
UPDATE (SELECT * FROM [MyTable] 
 ORDER BY [RowID]) SET [Ord]=GroupIncrement([RowID])
```

Create a third query:

```
TRANSFORM First([Description])
SELECT [Ord]
FROM [MyTable]
GROUP BY [Ord]
PIVOT [RowID]
```

This should put the data into the format you want (with an extra column on the left, Ord).

In Access, highlight that query and choose External Data, and in the Export section, choose Excel.  Export the query to Excel.

Open the file in Excel and delete the Ord column.